# Failing to get contents under input column

Tags: c#, selenium

I use C# with Selenium trying to get the contents of row, column and cell from a t able.  I have two columns, Name and Favorite Color.  I can get contents under the column Name, but I fail to get content under Favorite Color column.  The different between two columns is that, Favorite Color uses input tag.  Below is HTML page.

```
<div class="tableBlock">            
    <table class="tableTag">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Favorite Color</tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ken Master</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="yellow" class="favoriteColorInput"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Adon Matsui</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="red" class="favoriteColorInput"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Robert Carlos</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="Green" class="favoriteColorInput"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ronaldo Luis</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="Green" class="favoriteColorInput"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
  </table>  
</div>
```

I try the follow code to get the content, but I fail to get content under Favoire Color column because it returns back as empty string.

```
public void TraverseTableElement()
{
   //XPath to table
   IWebElement tagTable = 
       webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='tableBlock']/table"));

   //get all rows   
   IList<IWebElement> tagRows = tagTable.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

   string text = "";

   //getrow
   foreach (IWebElement tagRow in tagRows)
   {
      string td = "";

      //get all columns
      IList<IWebElement> tagCols = tagRow.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

      //get column
      foreach (IWebElement tagCol in tagCols)
      {
          td = tagCol.GetAttribute("value");
          text += td;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You are reading the `value` attribute on a `<td>` while it should be on an `<input>`.

Comment: I thought I was supposed to use GetAttribute() when trying to get value from the input tag.  But can you show the sample code you're refering to?  I use GetAttribute("input"), it does not work.  Sorry I'm fairly new to Selenium in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read value from `<input>` for the second column/td

```
//for columns with textbox
//Edit 24/01/2018
var byTagNameinput = By.TagName("input");
if(tagCol.IsElementPresent(byTagNameinput){
var inputElement = tagCol.FindElement(byTagNameinput);
text+= inputElement.Text
}
```

**====Edit 24/01/2018=====**
Yes, you guys are right, It will throw an error.
we have handled this by creating an extension method on IWebElement, which checks whether the item is present or not. You can use the same if you want.
This method needs to be created inside a static class

```
public static bool IsElementPresent(this IWebElement webElement, By by)
     {
            try
            {
                webElement.FindElement(by);
                return true;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: IWebElement tag = tagCol.FindElement(By.TagName("input"));
                    if (tag != null)
                    {
                        text += tag.Text;
                    }I'm getting exception that it cannot locate element "input".

Comment: If the element doesn't exist, it will throw an exception on the first line. Checking for `null` in the second line doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

To get the **values** under `Favorite Color` column you can use the following code block :

```
List<string> colors = new List<string>();
IList<IWebElement> options = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='tableBlock']/table[@class='tableTag']//tr//td/input[@class='favoriteColorInput' and @type='text']"));
foreach (IWebElement option in options)
{
    string temp = option.GetAttribute("value");
    colors.Add(temp);
}
```