# C# Selenium fails to get cell value from table based on tr and td tags

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I don't seem to know why my code cannot get cell value instead it always throws exception saying Additional information: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"html/body/div[2]/div[2]/table/tr[1]/td[0]"}

Below is my table HTML page.

```
<div class="tableBlock">            
    <table class="tableTag">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Favorite Color</tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ken Master</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="yellow" class="favoriteColorInput"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Adon Matsui</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="red" class="favoriteColorInput"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Robert Carlos</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="Green" class="favoriteColorInput"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ronaldo Luis</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" value="Green" class="favoriteColorInput"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
  </table>  
</div>
```

When I execute the code below it returns successfully with this string:

"table = "Name Favorite Color\r\nKen Master\r\nAdon Matsui\r\nRobert Carlos\r\nRonaldo Luis"

```
string table = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/table")).Text;
```

But when I try to get cell value based on row and column, it throws exception as mentioned above.  And here is the code to call to get cell value.

```
string cellVal = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]/table/tr[1]/td[0]")).Text;
```

So I wonder am I missing something?

thanks.

**Update:**

```
string cellVal = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/table/tr[1]/td[0]")).Text;
```

**Solved:**

With Chrome XPath helper, somehow it adds tbody in there which I don't have it in my HTML page, but after using it, it works.

Thank you everyone for helping.  Very appreciate.

Comment: unfortunately that does not work.  I just add the "/" slash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failing to get contents under input column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407651/failing-to-get-contents-under-input-column)

Comment: sorry if that is duplicated, but the earlier code from that post, it worked but my team lead reviewed my code and he didn't want me to use foreach loops.  He wants me to get cell value based on row and column.  I have tried different ways but still does not work.

Comment: If that Answer **worked** shouldn't it be accepted as an answer? Feel free to raise a new question with your exact new requirements. SO volunteers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: I'd also recommend looking into the [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) class so that you wait until the table is loaded. If your team lead wants you to do it based on row/column surely you could put some classes or ids on the columns then you could use `By.CssSelector("columnClassName")` to get the whole column then index in. It would be much cleaner than using `XPath`.

Comment: I agree.  XPath is very vulnerable to mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The issue caused by `td[0]`, in xpath, index start with 1 not 0, so change you xpath to `/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/table/tr[1]/td[1]`

Comment: Thanks Yong.  You're are correct about index 0.  However I tried different number index that's greater than zero but still exception thrown.  I just installed Chrome XPath helper to see the path tags to that table and oh boy, it uses "tbody" which I don't have.  I wonder if that is the issue because it works now.  I will further investigate when I go to work tomorrow.

Comment: But your given HTML code has no `tbody`, please update question if the  HTML code in question not exact.  If there is a tbody inside the table, try `/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]`

Comment: yeah I check it again, but my table does not have 'tbody" tag but according to Chrome XPath Helper extension, it includes that in there..  I will try your suggestion again when I can fix this SpecFlow license because right now it shows I have errors regarding with SpecRun which is a test runner for SpecFlow test automation tool.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can verify the xpath `/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/table/tr[1]/td[1]` manually in  Browser's DevTool.  And Please show the xpath by the Chrome Helper